# Make www.domain.com/admin points to a different directory other than /admin

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

The code is organized in the following directory structure:

```
/frontend/  
  index.php
  ...
/backend/  
  index.php
  ...
```

Note that `/frontend` and `/backend` are at the same level.

I have setup a virtual host that makes `www.domain.com` points to `/frontend/index.php`. Is it possible to make `www.domain.com/admin` points to `/backend/index.php`, without setting up another virtual host (e.g., `admin.domain.com`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Alias and ScriptAlias tags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/urlmapping.html#documentroot).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/admin/$ /backend/index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Seems that your solution doesn't work, because `www.domain.com` points to `/frontend`, with your RewriteRule, Apache will try to look for `/frontend/backend/index.php` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Ahh OK I get it, I thought you'd rewritten / to /backend/. In that case, open your httpd.conf and put a line `Alias /backend/ /full/path/to/backend/`